# efeito no input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bom montei um sistema e input bem preciso com o do android, usei CSS e jQuery.

Porém queria colocar um efeito preciso com o do material lite do google. 
Segue o link do exemplo: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section

Não quero usar o material lite pois o meu objetivo e tentar fazer um input baseando no material lite.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Segue o código que ja montei.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form_campos').on('focus blur', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
  }).trigger('blur');
  $('.select').on('change blur', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.form-group-select').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value !== ''));
  }).trigger('blur');

  $(".autofocus").trigger('focus');

  // Converte minusculas em maiusculas
  $('input').not('[name="link"]').on('input', function() {

    // Armazena posição corrente do cursor
    var start = this.selectionStart,
      end = this.selectionEnd;
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

    // Restaura posição armazenada anteriormente.
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
.form-group::after {
width: 100%; 
height: 2px; 
background:#0091FF; 
position: absolute; 
left:0; 
bottom:0; 
content: ''; 
transform: scaleX(0); 
transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}
.form-group.focused::after {
transform:scaleX(1);
}
.control-label {
    opacity: 0.4;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(5px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
    transform-origin: left top;
    transition: 240ms;
}
.form-group.focused .control-label, .form-group-select.focused .control-label {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.75);
}
.form_campos {
    height: 31px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #484848;
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.form_campos:hover, .form_campos:focus {
    border-color: #0091FF;
}
.form_disabled, .form_disabled:hover, .form_disabled:focus {
    border-color: #D7D7D7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='nome'>NOME</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos' id='nome' name='nome'>
</div>
<br><Br><br><Br>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label' for='idade'>idade</label>
  <input type='text' class='form_campos' id='idade' name='nome'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um `::after` no seu `css` com o formato da borda inferior, e usar a propriedade transform para redimencionar ele quando for atribuido o foco

Segue exemplo abaixo:
html

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='nome'>NOME</label>
    <input type='text' class='form_campos' id='nome' name='nome'>
    <div class="under"></div>
</div>
<br><Br><br><Br>
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label' for='idade'>idade</label>
    <input type='text' class='form_campos' id='idade' name='nome'>
    <div class="under"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-group .under {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 2px; 
    background:#0091FF; 
    position: absolute; 
    left:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    content: ''; 
    transform: scaleX(0); 
    transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
}
.form-group.focused input:focus + .under {
    transform:scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: caramba ficou show de bola. Muito obrigado

Comment: percebi um problema. Quando o input tem um valor o efeito não sai. Ele tem que acontecer apenas quando o select estiver selecionado.

Comment: Isso pode ser controlado checando se o input anterior está em focus, porem nesse caso não daria para usar um ::after mas funciona bem usando uma div
[pre]
 .form-group .under {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 2px; 
  background:#0091FF; 
  position: absolute; 
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  content: ''; 
  transform: scaleX(0); 
  transition: ease-in-out 240ms all;
 }
 .form-group.focused input:focus + .under {
  transform:scaleX(1);
 }
[/pre]
fazendo essa alteração, basta adicionar uma div.under depois dos inputs

Comment: poderia editar sua resposta? ai eu marco ele como resolvida.

Comment: Resposta editada

Comment: ok, funciona, mas não gostei de ter que criar um `div`, sera que não alguma forma de fazer isso com jquey? evitando a necessidade de criar um div em torno formulário.

Comment: Você pode fazer com que o jquery faça um append depois de cada input que estiver dentro do elemento .form-group

Comment: blz, isso eu sei fazer. com o `append` eu adiciono, mas como eu removo?

Comment: Você pode remover o elemento usando a propriedade .remove do jquery, você pode usar o remove em todos os elementos antes de adicionar um novo, deixando o html sempre limpo

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar o `addClass` e criar uma class com esse efeito?

Comment: o problema de adicionar apenas uma classe, é que o objeto precisa ser o objeto seguinte ao input, do contrario o css não irá identificar que ele está :focus.

Comment: entendi, bom de qualquer forma sua resposta foi 99% do caminho. vou ver como consigo finalizar o código aqui, muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo seu tempo.